# Entity framework - how to set StoreGeneratedPattern property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to set StoreGeneratedPattern property to 'Identity' which would be None by default. 
At the moment, I set this everytime when model updated as it reset to 'default' again. So, writing code to set it at runtime is the one way I can think of, is there any other best way to address this issue?

Comment: If memory serves, I had to do the same thing when using the designer - think the only way to do this would be through code (I personally didn't feel it was worth the effort considering how often the DB actually changed).

Comment: Thanks James. So, I am not doing something incorrect. that's fine

Comment: No it's just the way it works, ideally you would want it to work out what to set based on the field constraint but I think the idea is the model is not tied to the DB in anyway so all the configuration is manual.